During seeding, i faced this error "Attempt to read property "id" on null"
During seeding, i faced this error:
INFO  Seeding database.
Database\Seeders\RoleSeeder .................. RUNNING
ErrorException
Attempt to read property "id" on null
at C:\xampp\htdocs\cgpdocument\database\seeders\RoleSeeder.php:30
 26▕      [
 27▕        'id' => 'ff635a8f-4bb3-4d70-a3ed-c7749030696c',
 28▕        'isDeleted' => 0,
 29▕        'name' => 'Employee',
 30▕       'createdBy' => $user->id,
 31▕        'modifiedBy' => $user->id,
 32▕        'createdDate' => Carbon::now(),
 33▕        'modifiedDate' => Carbon::now()
 34▕      ],

1   C:\xampp\htdocs\cgpdocument\database\seeders\RoleSeeder.php:30
My migration is this:
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->boolean('isDeleted');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('createdBy');
        $table->string('modifiedBy');
        $table->string('deletedBy')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('createdDate');
        $table->dateTime('modifiedDate');
        $table->softDeletes()->nullable();
    });
}


Can you update your question with more of your RoleSeeder?

$user is most likely null, so it can't read the id of it. Show the rest of your RoleSeeder and how $user is defined.

Btw, xampp uses mariadb, not mysql, they just forgot to update their control panel...

As aynber said, $user is null, but your question does not include where $user is declared/instantiated.  This question Needs Clarity / Debugging Details.

Your $user object doesn't have an ID yet.
Ensure that you have the $user saved to the database, so that you can safely get it's ID.
